# Force submit parameter to be a specific type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that was build with FormGroup.

```
  <form [formGroup]="signInForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signInForm.value)"
        class="ui form attached fluid">
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui big left icon input">
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Username"
               [formControl]="signInForm.controls['username']">
        <i class="user icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <div class="ui big left icon input">
        <input placeholder="Password"
               type="password"
               [formControl]="signInForm.controls['password']">
        <i class="lock icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="big fluid ui blue submit button" disabled>Sign In</button>
  </form>
```

The component class looks as follow:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  signInForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.signInForm = fb.group({
      'username': [],
      'password': []
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(value: object): void {
    console.log('you submitted value:', value['username']);
  }

}
```

Consider the `value` parameter on the `onSubmit` method, it has object type.
My question is, can I specified a type for parameter `value`, for example class SignIn with particular properties?

Comment: Yes you can... however, the question is: for what do you want to pass the value in your `function` if you can access the value simply calling `.value`: `this.signInForm.value`?

Comment: I just start learning angular2, the example is from book. Thanks